# Why is my query not limiting the number of documents pulled from firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all users posts, newest first.

I have created a query for my Firestore like so:

```swift
postQuery = Firestore.firestore()
            .collectionGroup("userPosts")
            .order(by: "postTime", descending: false)
            .limit(to: 2)

// This call to load posts does not seem to load anything
// when I step through this with the debugger I see that it does not
// change the value of postArray which should be changed in loadPosts()
loadPosts()
```

Where my database looks like this:

```
posts(Collection)
   ---{userID}(Document)
         ---userPosts(Collection)
              {postID}(Document)
                  ---postTime(Field)
                  ---imageURL(Field)
```

How I am loading the data

```
//queries Firestore and loads into postArray
    func loadPosts() {
        postQuery.getDocuments{ [weak self](querySnapshot, error) in
            self!.q.async{
                guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                    print("No Posts")
                    return
                }
                var postsTemp = self?.postArray
                for doc in snapshot.documents{
                    self?.documents += [doc]
                    let post = self!.createPost(doc)
                    if(!self!.postArray.contains(post)){
                        postsTemp?.insert(post, at: 0)
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self!.postArray = postsTemp!
                        self!.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How I paginate my data

```
func paginate(){
        postQuery = postQuery.start(afterDocument: documents.last!)
        self.loadPosts()
    }
```

I then load the document fields into a cell of a table view whose methods are defined like so:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if postArray.count == 0{
        return 1
    }else{
        return postArray.count
    }
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Trigger pagination when scrolled to last cell
    if (indexPath.row == postArray.count - 1) {
        paginate()
    }
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var post: PostStruct
        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.imageView.image.sd_setImage(url: post.imageURL)// just an example
}
```

However, when I first load my app I watch it load all of the documents in my database without limiting it to just two and paginating when scrolled. This makes my app very slow and frequently runs out of memory. Why is it not being limited?

**Update**

`postTime` is the time the post was created, and is a string in the form: "2021-01-19 01:45:33 +0000". The strangest thing is that it appears to be loading the oldest first, so when I change descending to true, it doesn't load any posts. I have read through the Firebase documentation but cannot find any reason for this behavior.

**Update 2**

I suppose my most urgent question about this is why when descending is set to false I get posts returned but when it is set to true I do not.

Comment: I don't immediately see where you are reading the data from `postQuery`. Be sure to include the complete-but-minimal data with which anyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen Sorry about that forgot to include that function

Comment: shouldn't be `.limit(2)` instead `.limit(to: 2)`?

Comment: Your code looks good and should work I believe. I suggest you try to reproduce with a small collection group and simple code that logs how many documents were retrieved. If it still doesn't work share this example with us for further debugging.

Comment: @EmilGI this is a simplified version of what I am using. I am also only retrieving about 6 documents.

Comment: Have you created index for your collection group as documentation [suggests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)?